# indexOf and lastIndexOf in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

```
var home = "Home sweet home";
```

How do you find the index of the second `e` in sweet since both `home.indexOf("ee")` and `home.lastIndexOf("ee")` both return `7`. If JS takes `ee` as one unit and returns its' index, why can't it return the lastIndexOf that unit?

Comment: Just add 1 to the returned value

Comment: That's obviously a way to work around it but is there a way to get the index of the second "e" in sweet?

Comment: @AlfMoh That's not a workaround. It's a proper solution. You know that second "e" is at place "begining of the searched string + 1". Also you (should) know that `indexOf/lastIndexOf` returns the index at which **whole string** can be found. Thus you have to combine those two pieces of information and voila.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your input. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lastIndexOf` returns the index of the first character in the substring where the substring appears last in the superstring.

```js
var home = "Home sweet sweet home";
//                       ^ Matches here
console.log(home.lastIndexOf("ee"));
```

To find the second `e` when it forms part of the string `ee`, use `indexOf` and then add 1 (you know the second character of `ee` is 1 character past the first character of the substring, so you know to add that much, if you want the last character of the substring, then you can calculate it using the `.length` of the substring).

```js
var home = "Home sweet home";
//                  ^ Matches here
console.log(home.indexOf("ee") + 1);
```

To find the second `e` when it may or may not form part of the string `ee`, use `indexOf` to find the first `e`, and then use it again passing the index of the character after first `e` as the second argument.

```js
var home = "The fox ate the chicken";
//            ^       ^ Matches in these places
var first_index = home.indexOf("e");
var second_index = home.indexOf("e", first_index + 1);
console.log(first_index, second_index);
```

Answer (score 0):

index always starts from the left. lastIndexOf finds the last occurrence of the searched text (or unit, you might say) and returns the index of the starting of that unit (from left). Both the function are returning same index as there only one occurrence of the searches string "ee". If the home variable had another occurance of "ee", then you would get different result. Consider the following example:

```
var home = "Home sweet, sweet home";
home.indexOf("ee"); // will return 7
home.lastIndexOf("ee") // will return 14
```

Hope this clears your confusion

Answer (score 0):

Both of those methods return the "starting" index of the string you are looking for.

As stated in the Java documentation: [java.lang.String.lastIndexOf(java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(java.lang.String))

> The returned index is the smallest value k for which:
>
> this.startsWith(str, k)

So if you want to find the ending index of any string you are looking for there is an easy way:

```
var searchedStr = "ee";
var home = "Home sweet home";
var endIndex = home.lastIndexOf(searchedStr) + searchedStr.length - 1;
```